# (Challenge) Making a table with checklists and proper alignment

Tags: tables, formatting, lists

Perhaps you might want to take this question as some sort of challenge. I'm really just looking for the "most efficient way" of making a table similar to that in the image directly below (in LaTeX, of course):

[image]

I've attempted several different things, and ended up with a huge mess and a thousand packages in my preamble. (Here "thousand" is a hyperbole for "too much for my brain to keep track of".) Because I provided an image of what I want, I don't feel like any MWEs are necessary here.

Whatever looks most like the image I above, and gives the least headache, I'll mark that as the solution. Notice the days of the week are aligned to the horizontal centre of the cells, unlike the rest of the content.

**Note.** The table I provided as a reference was made using LibreOffice writer, and the immortal `CMU Serif` font. If you have a good eye, you'll have noticed that the content of the list elements are not aligned perfectly, as the second and following lines of all the list text blocks are pushed ever so slightly forward. This is neither intentional nor wanted.

Comment: How you try to solve this challenge yourself? Show us this. So far is not clear what is your problem ...

Comment: You can use `tabularray` and use list in cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Regarding your reputation, you should know, that this site is not service *we-will-do-your-task-instead-you*, so you should show what you try
- Question is not some challenge but rather simple table with lists which for labels has squares. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,
            margin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}  
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tblr}%
{%
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                  label=$\square$,%
                  itemsep=1ex,
                  leftmargin=*}%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = { Q[l] *{7}{X} },
             cell{2-Z}{2-Z}= {cmd=\RaggedRight,font=\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont},
             stretch = -1,%<--- remove extra space above and below lists
                        % with "nosep" option; tabularray doc p.51
             row{1}  = {c},
             measure = vbox,
             }
        & Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday & Saturday & Sunday \\
Morning &   \begin{itemize}
        \item   Some stuff and some more stuff
        \item   More stuff
            \end{itemize}
            &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   Some stuff and some more stuff
            \item   Some more stuff yet
                \end{itemize}
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item   Some stuff and some more stuff
                \item   Some more stuff yet
                    \end{itemize}
                    &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item   Some stuff and some more stuff
                    \item   Some more stuff yet
                        \end{itemize}
                        &   \begin{itemize}
                        \item   Some stuff and some more stuff
                        \item   Some more stuff yet
                        \item   Extra
                            \end{itemize}
                            &   \begin{itemize}
                            \item   Some stuff and some more stuff
                            \item   Some more stuff yet
                                \end{itemize}
                                &   \begin{itemize}
                                \item   Some stuff and some more stuff
                                \item   Some more stuff yet
                                    \end{itemize}   \\
Day         &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   Stuff
            \end{itemize}
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item   Stuff
                    \end{itemize}
                    &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item   Stuff
                        \end{itemize}
                        &   \begin{itemize}
                        \item   Stuff
                             \end{itemize}
                            &   \begin{itemize}
                            \item   Stuff
                                \end{itemize}
                                &   \begin{itemize}
                                \item   Stuff
                                    \end{itemize}
                                    &   \begin{itemize}
                                    \item   Stuff
                                        \end{itemize}   \\
        Evening     &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   Stuff
            \item   More stuff
            \end{itemize}
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item   Stuff
                    \end{itemize}
                    &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item   Stuff
                        \end{itemize}
                        &   \begin{itemize}
                        \item   Stuff
                             \end{itemize}
                            &   \begin{itemize}
                            \item   Stuff
                            \item   More stuff
                                \end{itemize}
                                &   \begin{itemize}
                                \item   Stuff
                                    \end{itemize}
                                    &   \begin{itemize}
                                    \item   Stuff
                                        \end{itemize}   \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

- Eventually selecting package for table and formatting of list require some effort, but for table you got good suggestion from @Clara, for formatting of lists are a bunch of examples how to do this. You only need to google a bit ...
- Writing table you should be aware that table is quite wide, so use `landscape` page orientation  is reasonable choice, also `\small` font size seems to give good looking result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your tidy and educative answer. I apologise if that's how my question went through. I agree with your thoughts, and will definitely make sure to ask a more precise question and show all my pertinent work next time. Thank you again, and have a great rest of your day.

Answer (score 4):

What about this as a start point? With some more work you can fix it as you like: alignment, spaces, lines ...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{bbding} % for square definition
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, total={267mm,180mm},left=10mm,top=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray} %for the table
\newcounter{tabitem}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\stepcounter{tabitem}\makebox[21pt][r]{\raisebox{-3pt}{\Square}\;\,}} %fot the \item square

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tblr}{vlines,hlines}
        & Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday & Sutarday & Sunday \\
        Morning & \tabitem \parbox[t]{3cm}{Some stuff and some more stuff} & \tabitem \parbox[t]{3cm}{This stuff is more stuff but not the same as the previous}\\
        Day& No list here & \tabitem \parbox[t]{3cm}{Some stuff is also present here}\\
        Evening & & \\
    \end{tblr}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: This is great, thanks. I've been having issues with placing lists inside table cells, but this seems to work fine with the `tabularray` package. I appreciate your answer.